# python main function run every two minute but some time main function requires analysis three minutes that time it executes half of the main function

Tags: python, time, program-entry-point, apscheduler

how to run the main function every two minutes and some function requires three minutes analysis after i will run two minutes?
I wrote code it analysis time three minutes sometimes it analysis takes two minutes depending upon the file size. how to run the function every two minutes after its analysis?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
def main():
#some machinelearning analysis
sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(main,'interval',minutes=2)
sched.start()
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you should be using `BlockingScheduler` instead if you run nothing else in the program, you already have the solution, don't you? What is the problem?

Comment: after two minutes completed it will re-run from the main function that time program not executing until the return statement. some time analysis required greater than 2 minutes.